# wants to play pcm packets getting form Windows Phone

Tags: java, windows, pcm

Hi Guys Hope you all doing well...
I an new in window Phone development and Writing a program in which getting audio stream from device but it is coming in PCM formats (Packets) and server need AMR so can any one guide me. I am now thinking about some kind of Encoder's written in java. If you have some solution please Guide.... :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [JSpeex](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/) and the .NET/SL port [NSpeex](http://nspeex.codeplex.com/)